# How to get timezone using strftime command?

Tags: vimrc, command, date-and-time

I have a custom command for stamping time in my log files. However, I would like that format to match the one of bash command `date`.

For example, I use this command:

```
:command InLog pu=strftime(\"\n***** IN:  %c\n\n\n\") | startinsert
```

which prints:

******* IN:  Thu Sep 16 01:51:47 2021**

However, I would want to have the same output as the `date` command in bash. Its output is:

**Thu Sep 16 01:52:48 EDT 2021**

Notice the EDT!

I would appreciate any help. :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not use the shell command itself with `system('date')`. So your command would be something like `:command InLog pu=printf("\n***** IN:  %s\n\n\n", system('date')) | startinsert`. (Unless you want to share this and need it to be portable...)

Comment: Part of the reason is because I am new to Vim so I did not know to do it the way you suggested. I like that method; however, there is an error. It says: Invalid arguments for function printf(

Comment: Hmmm. Put backslashes in front of the `"` like in your original command...?

Comment: how about: `:echo strftime('%a %b %d %T %Z %Y')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Christian Brabandt already gave the correct answer in a comment:

```
:echo strftime('%a %b %d %T %Z %Y')
```

I would like to add a few words.

The most important part from the help documentation:

> The accepted {format} depends on your system, thus this is not portable!
> See the manual page of the C function strftime() for the format.

So the actual valid format depends on your operating system, as Vim just uses the `strftime` available in the C library. Also most format specifiers *should* be portable, there might be differences.

The format specifier `%c` you used is described in the linux man page as:

> The preferred date and time representation for the current locale. ...

As that it doesn't need a timezone.

See `:help strftime()` (and your local C library documentation).

---

[Windows strftime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?view=msvc-160#generic-text-routine-mappings)

[Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)

Answer (score 0):

I have these in my .zshenv

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    export LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
    export TZ=Asia/Shanghai  # ref:   man tzselect
```

`set -g status-right "#[fg=red,dim]   %-d日 - %H:%M "` in my tmux config file,

`setl stl+=%{strftime('%H:%M')}` in my init.vim

Then almost all time I see is in "Asia/Shanghai"'s timezone.